# How to draw shape in canvas using ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

I have a program that have 4 text field and one button to draw rectangle, The text field for the enter of the number(x,y,x1,y1) and the button to add them(addO) , I need to know how to draw using the **action listener** with the **paint()** method inside the **canvas**?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: The question is vague.  I could recommend that you take a look at [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and still not answer your question

Comment: i want to take the number from the text field to the button by action listener and draw a shape using paint as simple as possiple

Comment: What's the number represent? What shape do you want to paint? Are this disconnected concepts?

Comment: simple shape square or oval

Answer (score 2):

The question is open and vague and the answer depends greatly on missing implementation details...

Essentially, getting a value from a `JTextField` is as simple as calling `getText` on an instance of the field...

```
private JTextField field;
//...
field = new JTextField(10);
add(field);
//...
String text = field.getText();
```

Converting the value to `int` would require you to use `Integer.parseInt(text)`.  This will throw a `NumberFormatException` error if the value is not a integer value.  Equally, you could just use a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) instead.

Using an `ActionListener` is a simply as attaching an instance of `ActionListener` to a `JButton`...

```
JButton doStuff = new JButton("Do Stuff");
doStuff.addActionListene(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // See previous comments about extract the field values...
    }
});
```

Painting in Swing is normally achieved by overriding `paintComponent` of a component that extends from `JComponent`, normally something like `JPanel` for example.

In this method you would paint whatever it is you need to...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

For example.

See:

- [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

For more details

Comment: how about displaying the shape in canvas?

Comment: *"Paint in Swing is normally achieved by overriding paintComponent of a component that extends from JComponent, normally something like JPanel for example"*

Comment: yeah i know, canvas??

Comment: same as 2d ?? if i cant in canvas how can i displaying them in 2d??

Comment: I don't understand.  Override the `paintComponent` method of something like `JPanel` and paint the shape, as show in the last code snippet